# log4j for logging a Web Application which is in production

Tags: servlets, logging, log4j

I am using log4j for logging Our Application which will be into production in three weeks.

Our Application will be deployed into remote location  server

We want to take help of lo4j if an user reports error while using the Application .

Regarding this I have some questions

1. What should be the path of the Log file generated ??
   For example (`log4j.appender.file.File=C:/app.log`)
2. Should we use `RollingFileAppender` or `DailyRollingFileAppender`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your remote server is on windows then path for log file will suits in the C directory.

else you can set any directory path and assign it to lo4j file like this

```
#log4j.appender.InputFieldFileAppender.File=${logs.root.directory}\\loging.log
```

DailyRollingFileAppender has been observed to exhibit synchronization issues and data loss. You can use InputFieldFileAppender if there is no special case.